# Nuget Packages Error Installing and Restoring "A circular reference to"

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Every time I try either install or restore any package for my VS 15 / .net 5 / EF7 project I receive this error regardless of the package. I have been looking and cannot seem to find anything for this error with nuget specifically. If anyone could help me understand what is going on here would be appercaited.

```
Restore failed
A circular reference to 'EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design' was detected.
NuGet Config files used:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config
Feeds used:
https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem when updating your project the problem was in the global.json file.

```
{
  {
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
    "sdk": {
     "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
   }
}
```

my problem was the sdk version never updated when I switched from beta-8 to rc1-final. So just change that and you should be ok.